# axios package takes to long by using get

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, axios, discord.js

I tried to load gifs with specific key words. But after like 7 files with different „Roleplay“ Commands which load different gifs it‘s only working sometimes and load‘s very long.

This is my code:

```js
const url = `https://tenor.googleapis.com/v2/search?q=hug%2C+anime&key=MYKEY&limit=5`;

axios.get(url).then(async (res) => {
        
const link = res.data.results[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)].media_formats.gif.url;
```